# How to include dependency with 'provided' scope with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven

I am fighting with maven to include a managed dependency with 'provided' scope into tar file by using the maven-assembly-plugin.

I use super parent pom file as a base for all of my projects. most of the projects will be deployed under application server so two common dependencies are declared under the super parent pom. below it is the relevant management section from the super parent:

```
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>super-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <name>super parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org.check</url>
.
.
.
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

log4j.version=2.0.8

in one of the inherited project (which is a standalone application), i am using maven-assembly-plugin with dependencySets in order to include the dependent libraries into a tar file. and of course I want also to include the log4j library.

below is the pom inherited from super parent:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xxx.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>plugin-cc-checker</artifactId>
    <name>plugin-cc-checker</name>
    <version>2.1</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.orca.integration</groupId>
                        <artifactId>integration-assembly-descriptor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly-according-to-distribution-xml</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
                            <!-- This is where we use our shared assembly descriptor -->
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>distribution-app.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            <version>${xerces.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-logging-api.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>excalibur</groupId>
            <artifactId>excalibur-i18n</artifactId>
            <version>${excalibur-i18n.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
            <version>${snmp4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

the distribution-app.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
    <!-- Add module dependencies and the jar that is created in the packaging 
        phase. Product name will be <project name>-app-<version no>.tar -->
    <id>app-${version}</id>
    <formats>
        <format>tar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>resources/app</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <!-- Since there is a bug in xalan 2.7.1 all applications required to 
                    use xalan-orca jar file -->
                <exclude>xalan:xalan</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <!-- includes> <include>*</include> </includes-->
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>/guy</outputDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j:log4j</include>
                </includes>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Why maven-assembly-plugin refuse to include the log4j into the tar file?
PS, trying to change scope to compile didn't work as well. I can'r change the declaration in the super parent pom.

Comment: I can see child pom does not have `version` for log4j ? Does it inherit that alone from parent in this case with over-ridden scope?

Comment: It will inherit the version from its parent pom. I tried to add the version anyway, but it still not making any differences.

Answer (score 13):

This can be done using the Assembly plugin.

First create an `assembly.xml` with the following:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Then just enable it in your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will create a yourproject-bin.jar that will include all the compile and provided resources exploded so they can be referenced in a classpath.

```
java -cp yourproject-bin.jar com.yourcompany.Main
```

Comment: Unpacking dependencies is always a very bad Idea.
Different libraries can have common files such as beans.xml meta-inf at the same locations.

Never unpack dependencies if you know what you are doing. Organize your assembly to have a lib/ folder. Then you will be fine. INclude the original JAR files do not extract anything! Ever.

Answer (score 10):

it is not possible to override the 'provided' scope in maven.

To solve this issue, I declared a variable in the parent pom that will define the artifact scope. In order to override the scope the only thing that has to be done, is to set new value for the variable in the inherited pom.

See example below:

parent pom:

```
    <properties>
            <log4j.version>1.2.8</log4j.version>
            <log4j.scope>provided</log4j.scope>
    </properties>
.
.
.
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <scope>${log4j.scope}</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Now in the child pom, just declare the variable again:

```
<properties>
        <log4j.scope>runtime</log4j.scope>
</properties>
```

Comment: It is possible to override a managed dependency by managing it in the child POM. See my answer below.

Comment: I don't want to down vote this because the idea of using a variable is compelling.  However, Zoltan is correct -- you can override a "provided scope" dependency using his "dependencyManagement" tag method.

Answer (score 4):

You can override a managed dependency by declaring it inside a `<dependencyManagement>` tag in the POM where you want it to be overridden.

In your case, you should add the following to your child pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Note that this overrides everything declared in the parent POM's dependency management, i.e. you cannot leave `version` or `scope` undeclared and expect it to be inherited.

Comment: and better than assembly ;)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue, trying to assemble a project with a dependency with scope "provided".
I found a workaround for this issue:

- Leave the dependency in "provided" scope
- Copy the dependency to the target folder using the maven-dependency-plugin ([example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html))
- Use a fileSet in the assembly descriptor to bundle the dependency as a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the scope into your [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html#class_dependencySet).

Comment: I tried to use the assembly descriptor, but it didn't work at all. No matter what.

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using and which version of the Maven-Assembly-Plugin ?

Comment: Maven version is 3.0.3, Maven-Assembly-Plugin doesn't have version, so it is the latest.

Comment: Actually maven 3.0.3 specifically uses version 2.2-beta-5 of the maven-assembly plugin in the super pom if not overridden.  It has a <pluginManagement> section that has versions for the antrun, assembly, dependency, and release plugins - with a comment stating that they will be removed at some point in the future.